# HTML/CSS bug I can't seem to fix

Tags: html, css

I created a website http://toucanandbutterfly.uk/ and on the Home Page the three boxes at the bottom work fine, but when you switch to any other page the boxes merge together, and the top bar changes size slightly. If anyone needs the HTML/CSS I am more than happy to give it.

Comment: When I click on policies, 2 elements from html are missing i.e. aside with class middle-sidebar and bottom-sidebar. This can be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the page source, the pages other than Home have this duplicated bit of HTML

```
<aside class="top-sidebar">
        <article>
```

Seems to be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally nested all of your "sidebar" boxes inside a "top-sidebar" box.

```
<aside class="top-sidebar">

    <aside class="top-sidebar">
        <h2> We're on Twitter.</h2>
   </aside>

<!-- Second side bar and third are different because of the Twitter thing. Good day!-->

    <aside class="middle-sidebar">
        <h2>Latest News</h2>
    </aside>

    <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
        <h2>Photo Library</h2>
    </aside>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes .. Your Source code is wrong. Correct it ..

On Your home page

```
<aside class="top-sidebar">
<aside class="middle-sidebar">
<aside class="bottom-sidebar">
```

is fine ..

but on the other pages you have created .. their code is mistakenly written.